# iOS - add padding to subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tapku

i add Tapkul calendar to my project , but as it mix with iphone time 
how can i add some padding from to my subview (calendar)

here my code to add it to my project

```
  calendar =  [[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] init];
    calendar.delegate = self;
    calendar.dataSource = self;
    calendar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,  320,400);


[self.view addSubview:calendar];
```

any suggestion

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
calendar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20,  320,400);
                               ^
-------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CGRectInset` like this:

```
calendar.bounds = CGRectInset(calendar.frame, 10.0f, 10.0f);
```

Comment: change bound to bounds